# Как узнать где определяется переменная

Tags: javascript, переменные

Привет. Есть очень большое приложение. Хочется научится отлаживать быстро и качественно. Как узнать в каком файле определяется переменная средствами фаербага? проблема в том ,что я не знаю всех файлов которые грузит сервер....Она (переменная) глобальная может можно какой то триггер прилепить, который будет срабатывать когда переменная глобальная запишется туда?

Answer (score 2):

Переключитесь на вкладку Сценарий в файербаге и воспользуйтесь поиском. Поиск ищет глобально по всем скриптам. Искать можно так: var имяПеременной, если конечно переменная объявлена через var.

Answer (score 1):

Разместите в начале `<head>`

```
<script>
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'varName', { set: function (){ debugger; } });
</script>
```

И смотрите коносль.

P.S. Так же этот код можно внедрить не редактируя страницу через [Conditional breakpoint](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42505328/jQuery-define.mov) (по ссылке видео).